# Read only recent data from the WebSocket buffer

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

How to read only the most recent data from the WebSocket buffer?

(discard all the previous data accumulated in the buffer)

I'm using the [Gorilla WebSocket](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket) package.

`Conn.ReadMessage()` seems to read the data sequentially,

So I tried `Conn.NextReader()`, because the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.NextReader) says:

> NextReader discards the previous message if the application has not already consumed it.

But I found that NextReader also works similar to ReadMessage.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

The code I tested:

```
_, r, err := c.NextReader() 
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)  // it reads the data sequentially, not the recent one.
```

Also tried this:

```
_, r, err := c.NextReader() 
buffer := make([]byte, 1024) 
nb, err := r.Read(buffer)  // seems to work the same way.
```

Comment: No, it can only be read sequentially. You can't seek a network socket. You can certainly read and discard messages until you reach what you're interested in.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you. Is there any decent way to discard messages until reaching the last one? I was just thinking: What if the server sends a load of messages, and the client's discarding speed is slower than receiving speed? (let's say the client needs only the most recent data). Maybe a silly question, but you get the point :)

Comment: There is no "last" message until the stream is disconnected. The other end can always send more as long as the connection is open. I don't think "discarding speed" is something you need to worry about, discarding a message is literally just the absence of processing it, which means you can discard them exactly as fast as you can read them.e

Comment: @Adrian Gotcha. So, I can't determine if there is a cumulated message beyond this current message until I read the 'next' message. Thus I need to store the most recent message, and if the next message is empty(for a while), then I can assume the stored last message is the most recent message. Thank you so much. Please let me know if I got you wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Storing the most recent message does not help because ReadMessage and NextReader block until a new message is available.  A possible solution is to enqueue messages to a processing goroutine where the processing goroutine discards all but the most recent message in the queue.

Comment: @Zombo Thanks. Yes, you're right, but how the processing goroutine knows if the incoming message is the most recent one?

Comment: I think I need another goroutine(and mutex maybe) to access and read the stored variable I mentioned above. The point here is if the variable is being overwritten or not, IMO. (For example, if we use a channel, it doesn't overwrite but rather queuing the data, so I think using a channel is not appropriate in this situation)

Comment: Create a channel of N elements and send messages to that channel.  In recieve processing routine, skip to the last value in channel before processing a message: `for m := range channel { for len(channel) > 0 { m = <-channel }; process(m) }` .  If the channel never fills (len(channel) is always less than cap(channel)), then the code in this comment processes the last known message.

Comment: @Zombo Thanks for your explanation with the example code! :)

Comment: You could also read from a goroutine into a channel and use a timeout in a `select` so that if a new message isn't receieved after some amount of time, you process the last one you got. A message is only the most recent until another one comes in. It might be helpful to reframe the problem as a timeout - "I want to process the last message received when no new messages are received for X amount of time".